# How can i turn this code into a helper function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, helper

I am trying to turn this conditional piece of code that i could probably improve by using a switch statement instead of an if statement into a helper function to minimize the amount of code i currently have within my component. How can i do this in a new file and import it to my component?

```
import { USER_TYPES } from '../../constants/user';

const usertypeToName = {
1: 'client',
2: 'supportWorker',
3: 'accountManager',
 };

 if (this.$route.params.userType === usertypeToName[1]) {
      return USER_TYPES.client;
    }
    if (this.$route.params.userType === usertypeToName[2]) {
      return USER_TYPES.supportWorker;
    }
    if (this.$route.params.userType === usertypeToName[3]) {
      return USER_TYPES.accountManager;
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: You can just do `userToName[$route.params.userType] ?? 0`  no need to check all the keys by hand there.

Comment: @TheFool there can be case where `userToName[$route.params.userType]` other falsy value, lets say a key named `default` exists but want to access only the given keys else return `0`, in that cases above will not work

Answer (score 3):

You should simply have `usertypeToName` as array and then use `find`

```
import { USER_TYPES } from '../../constants/user';

const usertypeToName = ['client', 'supportWorker','accountManager']
// find key
const key = usertypeToName.find(v=> v === this.$route.params.userType)
// use dynamic property accessor
return key ? USER_TYPES[key] : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
## util.js

import { USER_TYPES } from '../../constants/user';

const userTypeMap = {
  client: USER_TYPES.client,
  supportWorker: USER_TYPES.supportWorker,
  accountManager: USER_TYPES.accountManager,
};

export function mapUserType(name) {
  // Fallback to 0 incase mapping does not exist
  return userTypeMap[name] || 0
}


## component.js

import { mapUserType } from './util.js'

const userType = mapUserType(this.$route.params.userType)
```